# Are These Both The Same Or Different If Statements

Tags: c#, unity3d

**This is for unity**

I tried another way of stopping player after he dies and it worked fine but now it does not work with sounds

That was my way the only thing that I changed is the state

Ben's was

```
if  (state  ==  state.Alive) { Update() }
```

Mine was

```
if (state == state.Dying) { return; }
```

They look the same but the problem is the Success Sound will not play

Ben's code is working fine with me but I want to understand how it works

is mine the same?

```
void Update()
{
   if (state == State.Dying) 
   { 
       return; 
   }
   Rotate();
   Thrust();
}
```

Ben's way

```
void Update()
{
   if (state == State.Alive)
   { 
       Rotate();
       Thrust();
   }
}
```

For People Asking For The Enum Definitions:

```
enum State { Alive, Dying, Transcending }
State state = State.Alive;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `State`? Does it have only two possible values or are there others?

Comment: Do you have a link to the API docs for the list of `State` enum values?  If there are more than 2 than the two queries are not equivalent.  If you changed your statement to `if (state != State.Alive) { return; }` then they would be exactly equivalent.

Comment: What does single stepping through the code using the debugger tell you?

Comment: Another thought, if there is more inside the `Update()` method after the query for `State` then returning from the method early will cause all of that to be skipped.

Comment: If you're going to insist on the braces, they need to be on their own lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

**IF** `Alive` and `Dying` were mutually exclusive (i.e. it's always one or the other), then it would mostly be the same (see below for pedantic caveat). But as there is a third enum value, the behavior is different.

- In the first example, `Transcending` behaves the same way as `Alive` (as they are both `!= Dying`)
- In the second example, `Transcending` behaves the same way as `Dying` (as they are both `!= Alive`)

Which one is correct is up to you to decide.

---

One minor caveat, it's possible to use undefined values in an enum, e.g.

```
public enum MyEnum { A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 }

MyEnum test = (MyEnum)42;

Console.WriteLine(test == MyEnum.A); // false
Console.WriteLine(test == MyEnum.B); // false
Console.WriteLine(test == MyEnum.C); // false
```

Counterintuitively, `test` is a `MyEnum` yet it does not equal **any** defined `MyEnum` value. This means the earlier bullet points need to be slightly extended:

- In the first example, an unexpected enum value will cause rotation and thrusting.
- In the second example, an unexpected enum value will cause nothing.

You don't particularly need to defend against this at every turn, but in cases where you do value conversion, it's good to remember that using an undefined value does not register as a runtime error (by itself) but does lead to all expected equality checks failing.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this helped me understand enums a  lot better and I will revert back to bens method to do this.